# What's  > About This Mac > System Report > Software > Applications for?

Tags: macos, applications, mojave

[image: Screenshot of  > About This Mac > System Report > Software > Installations]

` > About This Mac > System Report > Software > Installations` shows you all of the installations on your Mac, but ` > About This Mac > System Report > Software > Applications` just says "No information found." I'm curious about what `System Report > Software > Applications` is for?

Comment: Why was this voted down?  I have the same question: "No information found" for all my applications.  If the System Info can't find my applications, how does the OS know about them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On mine MacBook Pro running Mojave 10.14.3 it just shows all the `.app`s on my computer.

[image: Applications]

Comment: This doesn't answer why the OP has the message "No information found."  (Yes, I know, the OP's picture is misleading, but the question remains unanswered.